# How to arrange the section and subsection number

Tags: sectioning

I want to arrange my section and subsection as follows:

1. Section

1.1 Subsection

1.1.1 subsubsection

1.1.2 subsubsection

1.2 subsection

2.Section

3.Section

---

My Latex file is below. Kindly suggest how to arrange section and subsection in my LaTeX file in accordance with the example above.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{xurl}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}

%%\usepackage{subfigure} % deprecated -- don't use it!

%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{color}

%%\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xtab}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}\Roman{subsection}}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Security in Optical network}

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}

\subsection{Energetic Attacks (EA)}

\subsubsection{In-band Jamming Attack}

\paragraph{In-band Jamming Attack}

\end{document}
```

The above file generates the following output which is not equal to the above one
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Do you use the `IEEEtran` document class because you currently write a paper you intend to sumbit to them? If so, do not change the template. If you use the documentclass for something different, you might want to consider switching to a different documentclass instead.

Comment: You are renewcommanding `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` to very strange values.  And I'm not convinced that your commands would give the output you show.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `texdoc IEEEtran` but got `Error: unknown Metadata type '???'`
so I don't know what that class does. However, using the `article` class instead the following changes the sectional numbering system as you say you want.

```
% secnumbersprob.tex  SE 572644

%\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{xurl}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}

%%\usepackage{subfigure} % deprecated -- don't use it!

%\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{color}

%%\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{xtab}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{abbrv}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[abbrv,1]{label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}

%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}\Roman{subsection}}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}


\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\title{Security in Optical network}

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}

\subsection{Energetic Attacks (EA)}

\subsubsection{In-band Jamming Attack}

\paragraph{In-band Jamming Attack}

\end{document}
```

It seems that `IEEEtran` doesn't want the numbering scheme to be changed. I haven't spent time deleting all your code that has nothing  to do with your problem. Your attempted change to the numbering scheme has nothing to do with what you are after.

If you are going to submit your document to the IEEE for publication then do not change the look that they want; if you do so they will most likely reject your submission.